# Col in Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I just started off learning Reactstrap and I'm using version 7.1.0
I've used this code (following the documentation),

```
<Row>

    <Col xs="3">.col-3</Col>
    <Col xs="auto">.col-auto - variable width content</Col>
    <Col xs="3">.col-3</Col>

</Row>
```

I am supposed to get the result in a single line(row), but I'm getting it in 3 different lines.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I added import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Answer (score 0):

are you trying this with a screen resolution for xs ? maybe you need to put other sizes than xs ? like sm, md...